# Docs for Spring are telling me that myRepository.findOne(Id id) returns the entity or null if none found but IntelliJ says differently

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, kotlin, warnings

I'm experimenting with programming in Kotlin using IntelliJ. I wanted to check if my entity returned by findOne() exists by checking if it's null but IntelliJ shows a warning:

> Condition 'visitRankEntity != null' is always 'true'

[image]

Am I missing something here? Why IntelliJ shows the warning?

@Edit

Okay, the warning disappeared when I added `?` after `VisitRankEntity`, so the line looks like:

```
 var visitRankEntity: VisitRankEntity? = visitRankRepository.findOne(WebfineryUtils.getDomainName(url))
```

Since I'm new to Kotlin I forgot about `?`. But shouldn't IntelliJ then warn me about that fact if the method can return null?

Answer (score 0):

Neither Kotlin nor IntelliJ know that a java function like `findOne()` would return null unless it had a `@Nullable` or similar annotation. When calling java methods that don't have nullity annotations, the type is neither `VisitRankEntity` nor `VisitRankEntity?` but rather a "platform type" which appears as `VisitRankEntity!`.  It basically means "I don't know if it is nullable or not."

Assigning/casting the `VisitRankEntity!` returned by `findOne()` to `VisitRankEntity?` is safe to do because it is more general, and will not yield a warning.

Assigning/casting the `VisitRankEntity!` returned by `findOne()` to `VisitRankEntity` will produce a compiler warning that says something like `Declaration has type inferred from a platform call, which can lead to unchecked nullability issues. Specify type explicitly as nullable or non-nullable.` If you happen to know `findOne()` will never return null, you can take that warning away by changing it to `findOne()!!` which basically adds a non-null assertion and casts it to the non-nullable `VisitRankEntity`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no syntax in Java to represent nullability. Even if there is a `@Nullable` annotation present the value might be null since there is no consensus about them (there is `@NonNull`, `@Nullable`, `@Nonnull` and some other variants) and **it is not enforced**.

Consider the following example:

```
val queue: Queue<String> = LinkedList()
queue.peek().toInt()
```

In this case you use peek which in fact can return `null` but the Kotlin compiler won’t complain so you can get a `NullPointerException` if your `Queue` was empty. The problem here is that we used `Queue` which is a JDK interface and if you look at the implementation of peek:

```
/**
  * Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue,
  * or returns {@code null} if this queue is empty.
  *
  * @return the head of this queue, or {@code null} if this queue is empty
  */
  E peek();
```

it says that `peek` will return `E` which will lead Kotlin to believe that `E` is not nullable because there is no `?` in the declaration (`E?`) and no annotation either. This might be worked around in a future version of Kotlin but right now it is important to keep this in mind in your projects and use these interfaces like this:

```
val queue: Queue<String?> = LinkedList()
queue.peek()?.toInt()
```

I've written about this extensively [here](http://the-cogitator.com/2017/10/02/kotlin-pitfalls-and-how-to-avoid-them.html) if you are interested.